# How to integration test prometheus metrics with no http requests

Tags: scala, integration-testing, prometheus

I have a server running that exposes metrics on port 8126.
I want to test the metrics recorded when I hit an endpoint in my tests.

Im now sending a http request to the exposed port, to get the recorded metrics.
for some reason, when no metrics has been recorded i get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Both 'Content-Length: 0' and 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' found
```

How do I capture the actual metrics recorded by my server and use them in my integration test? I saw lots of code examples on Github but they were all unit tests.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.